# Android Facebook

Tags: java, android

I have seen a few examples. But all allow the phone user to change the status that will be posted on their wall. Am I able to avoid this as my app will post a score and it will be pointless if the user can just put in any arbitrary number.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here.  Regardless of anything you do in *your* app, a user will be able to change their own status.  And if you don't want them to modify en-route a message that your app is posting, just don't provide that functionality in your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do.

1. Create a facebook application with the name of your game.
2. In the Android application ask use to authorize it posting to their wall
3. Stream to the application text/image/caption and that would be posted on their wall without user interaction.